# Does XMLConfiguration in Apache common support CDATA?

Tags: java, apache, cdata, xml-configuration

I'am using Configuration 1.6.

I hava a xml file, like

```
<property>
    <name>sql</name>
    <value><![CDATA[select a, b from c]]></value>
</property>
```

I wish to get "select a, b from c" as a whole string, but i get "select a" and "b from c" as List instead.

You may suggest I join the string's with commas, but somewhere else in my project depends on this property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the property of PropertiesConfiguration object like this:

```
AbstractConfiguration.setListDelimiter(0);
```

Setting the delimiter to 0 will disable value splitting completely.

That should work.

Comment: What does this mean? If i remove the CDATA flag, i will still get the value as List<String>

Comment: Nope. It shouldn't. You are trying to fetch the value of property. It wouldn't give you separated by comma or space without being explicitly mentioned.

Comment: I don't think so. I think the Configuration will provide you with List<String> no matter if you put the value in CDATA or NOT.

Comment: We will get to know if we execute right.Could you try that and post your reply?

Comment: I see what you are saying. Please find edits for modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Using commons configuration 1.9 it is recommend to use:

```
    config = new XMLConfiguration();
    config.setListDelimiter((char) 0);
    config.setDelimiterParsingDisabled(true);
    config.setAttributeSplittingDisabled(true);
    config.load(resource);
```